# Are there any Christians who understand Daniel 10 implying that there is an evil spirit prince over each country?

Tags: daniel, spiritual-warfare

The angel (I believe it is Gabriel) says:

> "Soon I must return to fight against the spirit prince of the kingdom
>   of Persia, and after that the spirit prince of the kingdom of Greece
>   will come."  ([Daniel 10:20; NLT](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=daniel%2010%3A20&version=NLT))

This assumes an evil spirit ruler over both countries and possibly more.  Are there any Christians<sup>1</sup> who understand Daniel 10 implying that there is an evil spirit prince over each country?

<sup>1. Any Christian meaning a particular Church or group, etc.</sup>

Comment: Opinions will vary on this. So this question is primarily opinion based. Please see: [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Answer (score 3):

To the question

*Are there any Christian traditions that speak of single nations being under the protection of an angel?*

The answer is **yes**. There is the common view among Church Fathers, consistent with Jewish Rabbis, that angels are entrusted to the spiritual care of kingdoms/nations.

This article [NATIONS AND LANGUAGES, THE SEVENTY: | Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11382-nations-and-languages-the-seventy) says:

> According to the Rabbis, each of the seventy nations is placed under
>   the protection of a special angel, except Israel, whose protector is
>   God Himself (Gen. R. xxxvii.).

And this article [Angels | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01476d.htm) says:

> Such appearances of angels generally last only so long as the delivery
>   of their message requires, but frequently their mission is prolonged,
>   and they are represented as the constituted guardians of the nations
>   at some particular crisis, e.g. during the Exodus (Exodus 14:19;
>   Baruch 6:6). Similarly it is the common view of the Fathers that by
>   "the prince of the Kingdom of the Persians" (Daniel 10:13-21) we are
>   to understand the angel to whom was entrusted the spiritual care of
>   that kingdom, and we may perhaps see in the "man of Macedonia" who
>   appeared to St. Paul at Troas, the guardian angel of that country
>   (Acts 16:9). The Septuagint (Deuteronomy 32:8), has preserved for us a
>   fragment of information on this head, though it is difficult to gauge
>   its exact meaning: "When the Most High divided the nations, when He
>   scattered the children of Adam, He established the bounds of the
>   nations according to the number of the angels of God".

I do not know when the guardian angels of the nations got their commission to explain some fallen angels being princes of certain nations.

---

**Endnote**

The **Jerusalem Bible Popular Edition** note on Dan 10:13 has:

> Michael ('Who-is-like-God?') is the guardian angel of the people of
>   God.